# MEAN starter kit showing error on installation

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I wanted a mean starter kit so that I can build my app. Then I got [this](https://github.com/giacomocerquone/angular4-mean-starter) from github. I just made it setup then made npm install and then made npm start. But it showed me several errors like this

```
[nodemon] 1.12.1
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[0] ✓ App is running at http://localhost:3000 in development mode
[0]   Press CTRL-C to stop
[0] 
[1] Cannot read property 'config' of null
[1] TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
[1]     at Class.run (/Users/Sites/tryouts/mean/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:51:63)
[1]     at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/Users/Sites/tryouts/mean/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:123:26)
[1]     at <anonymous>
[1]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

So can someone tell me how to make this working? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Comment: if i were you, just create it yourself, its simple to do and has less chance of failing

Comment: Any link or project where I can access a starter kit?

Comment: i dont believe there are any basic ones, this makes it off topic but follow the guide on scotch.io: https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli
and for the database connection: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications